# Como fazer um textBox que atualiza sempre que se muda o conteúdo?

Tags: c#, html5, webforms, textbox

Como se faz um `textBox` que atualiza na base de dados os valores que são colocados nele?

Isto é, o `textBox` está preenchido e o utilizador decide mudar o que lá está e queria que despoletasse* imediatamente um método para atualizar na base de dados a informação que foi colocada na `textBox`.

Estou a trabalhar em HTML e C# no *codebehind*.

---

<sup>* No Brasil, "disparasse"</sup>

Comment: Seria interessante mais detalhes como: o que você já fez? O que você não fez? Tem ideia de como fazer? Um pouco do seu código também ajudaria.

Comment: A aplicação ASP.NET é Webforms ou MVC ?

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mas o que significa "despoletasse"?

Comment: @ricidleiv É "disparasse" em português de portugal (pense numa espoleta). Aprendi com o Zuul no chat :)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, trabalhas com o Asp.Net Web Forms. A solução é simples: adicionar a propriedade `AutoPostBack` e escutar o evento `TextChanged`.

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MinhaTextBox" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="MinhaTextBox_TextChanged" />
```

CodeBehind:

```
public void MinhaTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Atualizar conforme MinhaTextBox.Text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função `javascript` que aciona uma `servlet` ou `webservice` toda vez que uma tecla for pressionada em seu textbox (ou `input` do html). Por exemplo em `jQuery`:

```
$('#nome-elemento').keypress(function() {
    var texto = this.value;
    $.post("endereco/da/servlet-ou-webservice", {"texto": texto}, function(retorno){
      //callback
    });
});|
```

Seria interessante que você estipulasse um tempo mínimo entre as gravações ou a servlet/webservice será chamada a cada caractere inserido na textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer utiliazr o banco de dados à medida que você for digitando num `textarea` do **html**, certo?

Se sim, você vai precisar utilizar o [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Existem alguns métodos para capturar a digitação do usuário no DOM: `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` são exemplos.

Teoricamente, a cada tecla digitada você deve enviar tal informação para o banco de dados - *e aqui você **deve** se preocupar com performance* - fazendo com que ele atualize alguma coisa por lá.

Imagine isso como um AJAX comum, só que ao invés de você estar enviando as informações através de um típico post, você estaria fazendo isso através de um outro tipo de engatilhador.

Fiz um exemplo para você:

```js
$('form textarea').on('keyup', function () { // quando você pressionar uma tecla no textarea...
    var $data = $(this).serialize(); // serializa a informação digita em uma variável
    
    $('.report').html($data); // exibe a informação serializada/digitada na div .report
    
    /**
     * depois, envia através de uma requisição post
     * as informações para '/path/to/action',
     * sendo tal endereço uma action do seu backend
     * escrito em C#.
     *
     * Lembrando que este backend tem a responsabilidade
     * de fazer a operação de banco de dados
     * que você deseja.
     *
     * Caso consigamos acessar a action, você cairá na função
     * 'success', onde imprimiremos no console
     * a resposta enviada pelo servidor.
     */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/action',
        data: $data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Se quiser brincar, ele está disponível [aqui, no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tBqX/).

<sub>*Você vai precisar de jQuery para rodar o exemplo.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar requisições **Ajax** junto com o **change** do campo, mas é melhor disparar a requisição com base em um **click** de um botão salvar, imagine acessar o banco a cada letra que o usuário digitar, isso seria bem ruim em algumas ocasiões.

**Ajax** (jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
**Change** (jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/change/
**Click** (jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada no [AngularJS](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GtaQ0oMGIl/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs).

É um framework em Javascript que coloca estados de execução nas paginas criadas por ele.

Desta forma você consegue criar um modelo (em js), atualizar estas informações do modelo e o próprio angularjs propaga as atualizações para seus componentes na página.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, primeiro você precisa usar o `AngularJS`. Se não conhece esse framework, te aconselho a parar tudo que esta estudando para dar uma olhada nele. Ele é extremamente simples de entender e muito poderoso. Ele possui a característica que você está querendo, que é o `binding` automático. Se você der uma olhada [nesse site aqui](http://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-simples-com-angularjs/), você encontrará um tutorial bem rápido e simples, mas que faz o que precisa.

Outra coisa que posso te falar é usar uma ação `ajax` para salvar o que foi escrito no banco de dados, utilizando qualquer tecnologia server-side para isso. O proprio `AngularJS` tem sua maneira simples e prática de fazer isso :

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);)
```

Segue um exemplo claro do que estou falando:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dradev/ta7Wc/)